# How to extract specific value using grep and awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I am facing a problem to extract a specific value in a .txt file using **grep** and **awk**.
I show below an excerpt from the .txt file:
"-

```
 bravais-lattice index     =            2
 lattice parameter (alat)  =      10.0000  a.u.
 unit-cell volume          =     250.0000 (a.u.)^3
 number of atoms/cell      =            2
 number of atomic types    =            1
 number of electrons       =        28.00
 number of Kohn-Sham states=           18
 kinetic-energy cutoff     =      60.0000  Ry
 charge density cutoff     =     300.0000  Ry
 convergence threshold     =      1.0E-09
 mixing beta               =       0.7000"
```

I also defined some variable: ELEMENT and lat.
I want to extract the "unit-cell volume" value which is equal to 250.00.
I tried the following to extract the value using grep and awk:

```
volume=`grep "unit-cell volume" ./latt.10/$ELEMENT.scf.latt_$lat.out | awk '{printf "%15.12f\n",$5}'`
```

However, when i run the bash file I always get 00.000000 as a result instead of the correct value of 250.00.

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{printf "%15.12f\n",$5}'
```

You're asking awk to print out the fifth field of the line (`$5`).

```
 unit-cell volume          =     250.0000 (a.u.)^3
 1         2               3     4        5
```

The fifth field is `(a.u.)^3`, which you are then asking awk to interpret as a number via the `%f` format code. It's not a number, though (or actually, doesn't start with a number), and when awk is asked to treat a non-numeric string as a number, it uses 0 instead. Thus it prints 0.

Solution: use `$4` instead.

By the way, you can skip invoking grep by using awk itself to select the line, e.g.

```
awk /^ unit-cell/ {...}
```

The `/^ unit-cell/` is a regular expression that matches "`unit-cell`" (with a leading space) at the beginning of the line. Adjust as necessary if you have other lines that start with `unit-cell` which you don't want to select.

Answer (score 1):

You never need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do. It sounds like this is all you need:

```
$ awk -F'=' '/unit-cell volume/{printf "%.2f\n",$2}' file
250.00
```

The above works because when FS is `=` that means `$2` is `<spaces>250.000 (a.u.)^3` and when awk is asked to convert a string to a number it strips off leading spaces and anything after the numeric part so that leaves `250.000` to be converted to a number by `%.2f`.

In the script you posted `$5` was failing because the 5th space-separated field in:

```
    $1         $2    $3      $4         $5
<unit-cell> <volume> <=> <250.0000> <(a.u.)^3>
```

is `(a.u.)^3` - you could have just added `print $5` to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are processing key-value pairs where the key can have variable amount on space in it, you need to tune that field number ($4, $5 etc.) separately for each record you want to process unless you set the field separator (FS) appropriately to `FS=" *= *"`. Then the key will always be in $1 and value in $2.

Then use `split` to split the value and unit parts from each other.

Also, you can loose that `grep` by defining in awk a pattern (or condition, `/unit-cell volume/`) for that `print`action:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *= *"} /unit-cell volume/{split($2,a," +");print a[1]}' file
250.0000
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=" *= *" }   # set appropriate field separator
/unit-cell volume/ {   # pattern or condition
    split($2,a," +")   # split value part to value and possible unit parts
    print a[1]         # output value part
}' file
```